# Getting response from django rest endpoint (Search bar)

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django and need to make search bar in my django-react project. Need to take data from input, send it to django and, as response, receive new queryset. I'm using axios and django-rest framework. From input field within React "Search" component I'm intending to send data via axios like:

```
    getQuery = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/SearchPost?q=${this.state.query}`)
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            data: res.data
        });
```

input in React:

```
    handelChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ query: this.search.value},
        () => {
            this.getQuery()
        })
}

render() {
    return (
        <form>
            <input
                placeholder="Search..."
                name="q"
                ref={input => this.search = input}
                method="get" 
                onChange={this.handelChange}
            />
        </form>
```

my view.py in django is:

```
class SearchPost(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    def search(request):
        query = request.GET.get("q")  
        if query:
            queryset = Model.objects.filter(
                Q(category_icontains=query)|   
                Q(title_icontains=query)|
                Q(creator_icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
```

in urls.py:

```
path('api/SearchPost', views.SearchPost.as_view()),
```

but, as a response I'm reciving nothing.
Things I'm asking myself is:
 1) Am I sending axios request to the right endpoint?
 2) Should I return something in my view.py "SearchPost" class?

Any advices are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your API as follows

```
      class SearchPost(generics.ListAPIView):
          serializer_class = ModelSerializer  //please change name of serializer
          model = serializer_class.Meta.model
          paginate_by = 100
          def get_queryset(self):
              query = self.kwargs.get('q')
              if query:
                  return self.model.objects.filter(
                    Q(category_icontains=query)|   
                    Q(title_icontains=query)|
                    Q(creator_icontains=query)
                    ).distinct()
              return None
```

We use ListAPIView as we are only listing in a search endpoint.

Comment: but now I'm facing KeyError with 'q'. Idea?

Comment: @yoora update path `path('api/SearchPost/<str:q>', views.SearchPost.as_view())`

Comment: Thank you for you time Jibin. Still getting "404 Not found" when I type something in search bar